# What is the value of 'auto' in the input field

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input name="Username" type="text" id="Username" width="auto" height="auto">
```

I want to know the value of auto... the Integet value behind this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use javascript:

```
document.getElementById("Username").clientWidth

document.getElementById("Username").offsetWidth
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no integer value behind it, it is a validity error. Input elements do not have a `width` (or a `height`) attribute, and no `width` attribute in HTML takes `auto` as a value.

The attributes will be ignored and the size of that element will be determined by the usual pattern of user stylesheet falling back to author stylesheet falling back to browser stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input name="Username" type="text" id="Username"  width="auto" height="auto">

<script>
alert(document.getElementById('Username').offsetWidth); //chrome and others
alert(document.all.Username.offsetWidth); // for ie and chrome
</script>
```

Comment: Internet Explorer has happily supported `getElementById` for a very long time. You only need to go near `document.all` if you need to support Internet Explorer 4 (which you don't). There is no reason for `document.all` to appear in code written today.

Comment: thanks i put that because i'm used to, but it's true that the getElementById is now supported ;)

Answer (score 0):

"Auto" is the default value of a text box height.

If you don't want to specify width or height of the textbox, HTML accepts auto as a value.

Hope this helps.